# Where can I set appery.io activeScreen page name?

Tags: ionic-framework, appery.io

Developers.
I am now developing ionic app, and I`m using appery.io.
And I added new route and page.
But I don`t know where can I set page name in Header.

In which file can I set activeScreen page name.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the header to be the same at all pages then you can open `index` inside `Pages` and set header text there as described in [Buiding Your First Ionic App](https://blog.appery.io/2016/06/tutorial-building-your-first-ionic-mobile-app/) tutorial.
Or you can make it dynamic as described in [Building a Native App with Ionic, AngularJS and Appery.io](https://blog.appery.io/2015/08/building-a-todo-app-with-ionic-angular-and-appery-io/) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your briefing.